# How to create a image slider with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, slider, styles

I am trying to add an image slider on my site. My image is of the size 1650 by 350 and there are 4 images of this exact size. I have tried to do this with HTML and CSS, but unfortunately, the images are not moving automatically, I tried to make it move automatically in the CSS. I wonder what could be wrong.

CSS:

```
.slider {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
    width: 2000px;
    background-color: pink;
    height: 350px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s;
    -moz-transition: left 2s;
    -o-transition: left 2s;
    transition: left 2s;
}

.slide {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#slide-1:target~.image-container {
    left: 0px;
}

#slide-2:target~.image-container {
    left: -1600px;
}

#slide-3:target~.image-container {
    left: -3200px;
}

#slide-4:target~.image-container {
    left: -4800px;
}

.buttons {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

.buttons a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <span id="slide-1"></span>
  <span id="slide-2"></span>
  <span id="slide-3"></span>
  <span id="slide-4"></span>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="./assets/slider-1.jpg" class="slide" width="1650" height="350" />
    <img src="./assets/slider-2.jpg" class="slide" width="1650" height="350" />
    <img src="./assets/slider-3.jpg" class="slide" width="1650" height="350" />
    <img src="./assets/slider-4.jpg" class="slide" width="1650" height="350" />
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#slide-1"></a>
    <a href="#slide-2"></a>
    <a href="#slide-3"></a>
    <a href="#slide-4"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, the slides move on click but not automatically?

Comment: @JayCodist Its not moving on click either

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a codepen?

Comment: And to be clear, you goal is to achieve this with only HTML and CSS?

Comment: Yes, I want HTML and CSS or if you have a better approach. I have 4 images in 1600 by 350 px

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)?
Just add css and the script and you have a carousel ready out of the box.

Comment: Looks good, do I have to create those class names? This is boostrap

Comment: [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: btw ,other than the css remember to put the bootstrap js as well